# Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 - apply rename using only one shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, rename

How can I apply/accept a rename using only one shortcut?

I already know there are some solutions, but those require more than one shortcut:

- Edit; **Ctrl + .** (Show potential fixes); **Enter**.
- Select the text; **Ctrl + r**;  **Enter**.

The solution I'm seeking: Edit; **some key combination**; You are done! Like in Matlab, you just need to press **Shift+enter**.

Comment: At the risk of being a grouch, what's wrong with Ctrl . and Enter? A character less won't get you nearer to Christmas.

Comment: Its is the double. Double is too much. It is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command (Language: C#) for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to automate  Ctrl + . (Show potential fixes); Enter:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.QuickActions");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```